# Is f(n) = n O(n) time or O(1)?

Tags: python, big-o

I understand that usually you'd just ignore the coefficient when trying to figure out how complex a given algorithm is, but say I have a variable *n* in a for loop:

```
[(n, n) for n in range(1,11)]
```

, which returns

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10)]
```

Isn't this assignment just an O(1) operation? We don't do any manipulation with *n* whatsoever. Or am I misunderstanding the meaning of it - perhaps the O(n) time describes how long it takes to loop through and make all these assignments?

Context is the following code, which I wrote for a school project.

```
#Michael Frake, CMSC 350, UMGC, 5/22/2021

print("{:<7} {:<8} {:<8}".format('i','f(i)','g(i)'))
for i in range(21):
    print("-", end="")
print()
for i in range(1, 25, 1):
    f = (i / 2) + 10
    g = i
    print("{:<7} {:<8} {:<8}".format(i,f,g))
    if g > f:
        print("g overtook f when i was ", i)
        break
```

which returns

```
i       f(i)     g(i)    
---------------------
1       10.5     1       
2       11.0     2       
3       11.5     3       
4       12.0     4       
5       12.5     5       
6       13.0     6       
7       13.5     7       
8       14.0     8       
9       14.5     9       
10      15.0     10      
11      15.5     11      
12      16.0     12      
13      16.5     13      
14      17.0     14      
15      17.5     15      
16      18.0     16      
17      18.5     17      
18      19.0     18      
19      19.5     19      
20      20.0     20      
21      20.5     21      
g overtook f when i was  21
```

where I was trying to see if there was a difference in the time complexity of these two functions.

Comment: I must be missing something, I don't really understand what you are asking: "Isn't this assignment just an O(1) operation?" What "assignment"? `[(n, n) for n in range(1,11)]`, as an algorithm, is constant time, *indeed, it doesn't have varying inputs at all*. The fact that you use a variable named `n` is irrelevant.

Comment: It is true that the "assignment" (`n = 1`, `n = 2`, etc.) is O(1), but I was referring to the function as a whole, so really the only relevant thing I didn't understand was that a `for` loop processes in O(_n_) time where _n_ is the number of iterations of that loop. For some reason I thought that what type of arithmetic you did in the function was the determining factor, hence my confusion as to the role of _n_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing the notation a bit. `n` in O-notation refers to the number of input elements (or number of iterations *depending on* the inputs). It does not have anything to do with how you name your variables.

So it would rather be:

```py
[(value, value) for value in range(1, n)]  # O(n)
```

Where `n` can be chosen arbitrarily hence this simple for-loop runs in `O(n)`. If it was constant, e.g. because you always run exactly 21 elements as it is is in your case, it would be just `O(21) = O(1)`.

```py
[(value, value) for value in range(1, 21)]. # O(21) = O(1)
```

This would change if we did something like this:

```py
elements = list()

for i in range(n):       # O(n)  -> Depending on "n" (number of inputs)
    for j in range(21):  # O(21) -> Constant
        elements.append((i, j))
```

This would be denoted as `O(n) * O(21)` which would be reduced to simply `O(n)` because the worst-time complexity depends on `n`, the number of input elements.

Just for completeness, the following would be `O(n²)`:

```py
elements = list()

for i in range(n):       # O(n)
    for j in range(n):   # O(n) 
        elements.append((i, j))
```

Comment: I realize now I just needed the connection with loops and O(n) (n being the number of iterations), depending on how many loops there are of course. I was stuck on the actual operation itself (`variable = 1`, `variable = 2` vs `variable = 1 ^ 2`, `variable = 2 ^ 2`), thinking that was somehow relevant.